# Как отобразить на странице загруженное пользователем изображение

Tags: java, html, servlet, tomcat

Нужно отобразить изображение на странице, данные о изображении хранятся в бд поля( `int idphoto, varchar title, varchar location, int logins_idlogin`) в `location` хранится путь к файлу в каталоге куда они сохраняются. Если просто зайти на страницу и в каталоге для изображений есть картинки они отображаются, но если добавить новое все данные о изображении будут отображены, но само изображение - нет, если перезапустить проект - это изображение уже будет отображено. Не знаю в чем заключается проблема:

`LoadDataServlet` - сервлет который вызывает страницу на которой будут отображены изображения и передает в `List'е` нужные данные

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoadDataServlet", urlPatterns = "/loaddataservlet")
public class LoadDataServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/photolibrary";
        String USER = "root";
        String PASSWORD = "25Lionheart";

        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet rs;
        List dataList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "Select * from photos where logins_idlogin='"+TempName.tString()+"'";
            statement.executeQuery(sql);
            rs = statement.getResultSet();
            while(rs.next()) {
                dataList.add(rs.getString("title"));
                dataList.add(rs.getString("location"));
                dataList.add(rs.getInt("idphoto"));
            }
            rs.close();

        } catch(Exception e) { }

        request.setAttribute("data", dataList);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("load.jsp");
        if (requestDispatcher!=null) {
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Load.jsp - страница на которой отображаются отображение и есть возможность добавить новое:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-attachment: scroll; /* Фиксируем фон веб-страницы */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/addphoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Input photo title:</label>
  <input type="text" size="35" name="title">
  <div>
    <label>Select photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="select">
  </div>
</form>
<center>
<table borde="1" width="303">
  <%Iterator itr;%>
  <% List data= (List)request.getAttribute("data");
    for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
  %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=itr.next()%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><A HREF=><img src="<%=itr.next()%>"></A></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="/deleteservlet?id=<%=itr.next()%>">
        <input type="submit" value="del">
        </form>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <%}%>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

AddPhoto - сервлет при помощи которого мы добавляем изображение и после завершения опперации возвращаемся на load.jsp

```
@WebServlet(name = "AddPhoto", urlPatterns = "/addphoto")
public class AddPhoto extends HttpServlet {

    private Random random = new Random();

    String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/photolibrary";
    String USER = "root";
    String PASSWORD = "25Lionheart";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(!isMultipart) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(1024);

        File tempDir = (File)getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
        factory.setRepository(tempDir);

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setSizeMax(1024*1024*10);


        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();

            String title = null;

            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                if(item.isFormField()) {
                    title = item.getString();
                } else 
                    processUploadField(item, title);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){}
        response.sendRedirect("/loaddataservlet");
    }

    private void processUploadField(FileItem item,String title) {
        File uploadFile = null;
        String path;
        String path1 = "/lib/"+TempName.id+"/"+title+".jpg";
        do {
            path="D:\\photo library\\project\\web\\lib\\"+TempName.tString()+"\\"+title+".jpg";
            uploadFile = new File(path);
        } while (uploadFile.exists());

        try {
            uploadFile.createNewFile();
            item.write(uploadFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println(uploadFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "Insert into photos(idphoto,title, location, logins_idlogin) values('"+random.nextInt(100000)+"','"+title+"','"+path1+"','"+TempName.id+"')";
            statement.execute(sql);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Что за сервер используете, и как отдача картинок настроена?

Comment: apache tomcat, изображения отдаются с помощю List(где хранится имя, путь и ид) и передается в load.jsp

Comment: Если у вас не статичные картинки в war-ке, тогда, на сколько я понимаю, необходимо запилить сервлет, который будет отдавать файлы, а на странице ссылки на этот сервлет.

Comment: я не разбираюсь, но рискну предположить. Томкат по-умолчанию не отдает файлы из произвольного места в файловой системе, а только файлы, которые были в .war. При перезапуске проекта вы пересобираете war, и в него попадают все новые файлы, и сервер начинает их отдавать. Вам нужно или написать свой сервлет, который будет читать файл в `response.getOutputStream` или [сконфигурировать](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/) Tomcat

Comment: Спасибо, попытаюсь последовать вашему совету